# there's no way to use dart3 incompatible package?

Tags: flutter, package, audio-player, incompatibletypeerror, piano

I'm beginner for android developer. (for fun)
I want to make sheet music quiz app with flutter.
so I tried to find sheet music render package.

I found two package (`piano`, `sheet_music`)

But

- `sheet_music` package - dart3 incompatible
- `piano` package - only show me interative piano.

**Q1.** how can i use dart3 incompatible package?

**Q2.** or can i render sheet music with piano package?

piano package's basic usage is

```
return CupertinoApp(
        title: 'Piano Demo',
        home: Center(
          child: InteractivePiano(...
```

---

so i changed

```
return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Piano Demo',
      home: Center(
        child: ClefImage(
          clefColor: Colors.white,
          clef: Clef.Treble,
          noteColor: Colors.white,
          noteImages: [NoteImage(notePosition: NotePosition(note: Note.C, octave: 4),),],
          noteRange: NoteRange(
            NotePosition(note: Note.C, octave: 4),
            NotePosition(note: Note.C, octave: 5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i'm expect 5 lines sheet music.
but i only got black screen